# Ionic versions - understanding difference between ionic cli version and ionic core version

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I am starting to work on an existing Ionic 4 application. In that project @ionic/core version is 4.8.1. To start, I installed ionic CLI and noticed its version to be 5.4.15. I was not able to find easily if I can install an older ionic CLI version.

However, I feel CLI version and the application version need not be the same always. So, now, I would like to know how these things are related. Also, for me to run my existing project, can I use the same version of ionic CLI.

I wanted to mention that all ionic-native/**** references are 5.10.0 which I think should fine as @ionic/core and @ionic/angular is the version which says what my ionic project version is.